# Using a CSV as datasource JasperServer: CSV changes

Tags: rest, csv, jasperserver

**I'm creating reports using JasperSoft Studio 6.8.0 and looking at them on JasperSoft Server**

I was wondering how to use a CSV as a datasource, I've managed to get it working on the server, but whenever I make changes to the CSV these are not shown in the report.

I've tracked this down to whenever I publish report it will also save a copy of the CSV file to the server, which I'm assuming it then looks at, this is strange to me as the XML looks at,for example,  T:\Folder\CSV.csv.

How can I instead have it look at an XML without it needing that 'local' copy?

I've tried making use of file//pathtofile, but this causes the same problem.

Do I need to use JasperServers REST API in order to upload the file whenever a new one is created, which is daily, or is there some part of the data adapter process I'm missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out where I was going wrong.

I shouldn't have ever been using the T:\ or file:\  instead I need to make use of the actual server that the file was stored on so \\server2\folder\file.csv this has now worked and I can update the file freely.